# D3.js roll up nested data

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, content-query-rollup

please help me

I've got a json file like this.

```
 [
{
    "Paket": [
        {
            "farbe": "#ff0000",
            "Koordinaten": [
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": "469\/31 A 1; A 3; A 4",
                    "y": "5",
                    "x": "0"
                },
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": "469\/31 A 1; A 3; A 4",
                    "y": "5",
                    "x": "150"
                },
                {
                    "paketaufenthaltsort": "469\/31 A 1; A 3; A 4",
                    "y": "0",
                    "x": "150"
                }
            ],
            "Paketnummer": "11000005"
        }
    ],
    "offset": "5",
    "referenzzeitraum": "1440"
}
 ]
```

and now I want to have an array containing all values of "paketaufenthaltsort".

So I've tried the following:

```
console.log(data.map(function(d)
{return d.Paket.map(function(e) 
{return e.Koordinaten.map(function(f) {return
f.paketaufenthaltsort;})})}));
```

But it produces an array of level 3. 
The outcome is:

```
   [[["469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4", "469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4", "469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4"]]]
```

But what i want is:

```
["469/31 A 1; A 3; A 4"]
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call `map()` on the outer arrays, because you are only interested in the array `Koordinaten`. Only this array needs to get mapped to the desired output by replacing the contained objects with the value of the property `paketaufenthaltsort` of each individual object. You will just need to iterate over the outer arrays by invoking [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on each of these arrays:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Paket.forEach(function(p) {
        var orte = p.Koordinaten.map(function(k) {
            return k.paketaufenthaltsort;
        });
        console.log(orte);
    });
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvpxck7p/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
console.log(data.map(function(d){
return d.Paket.map(function(e) 
{return e.Koordinaten.map(function(f) {return
f.paketaufenthaltsort;})})[0][0][0]}));
```

which will access the first element of the nested array.